# Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed using express

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, express, jestjs

I'm using JEST for unit testing my express routes.

While running the `yarn test` all my test case are getting passed, but I'm getting an error

```
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
```

I used `async` & `done`, but still it throws the above error.

Below is my spec code. Please help

**routes.spec.ts**

```
const request = require('supertest');
describe('Test the root path', () => {
  const app = require('./index');

  test('GET /gql/gql-communication-portal/release-notes', async (done) => {
    const response = await request(app).get('/gql/gql-communication-portal/release-notes');
    expect(response.status).toBe(200);
    done();
  });
});
```

Comment: `app = require('./index')` does this start the server listening on a port? ideally your server should be set up so it can be imported without actually starting it, which is what you want to do in this instance. It might also resolve your issue.

Comment: must remember to look at "asked" date..

Comment: Because you use a promise in the code snippet you provide, it looks like you don't need the `done()` callback in your `GET` test. I have a similar scenario where I just use `async` and `await`. [Here](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#callbacks) is where the Jest documentation talks about callbacks as an alternative to `async` `await` promises. Not directly related to your question, but perhaps useful for future readers like myself.

Answer (score 95):

My problem was solved by this code:

```js
beforeAll(done => {
  done()
})

afterAll(done => {
  // Closing the DB connection allows Jest to exit successfully.
  mongoose.connection.close()
  done()
})
```

Comment: I had the same problem, only it was with mysql. I closed the connection with mysql, and it works. Thanks

Comment: This answer must be accepted.

Comment: adding done() solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: If you are using `typeorm` in `Nestjs`, close db connection solve the problem. In `afterAll` do `moduleRef.get(Connection).close()`

Comment: `mongoose is not defined`

Comment: are these supposed to go in the file that opens the connect, or in the jest test file?

Comment: You are a lifesaver. I didn't think for a million years that this could be the problem. Even ChatGPT wasn't helpful. Then I came across this answer and thought, "Why don't I close my DB connection and see if it solves it!" (I'm using Prisma btw). And it did! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: You don't have to use `done` to "await" the connection close. This will also work: `afterAll(() => mongoose.connection.close())`

Answer (score 33):

I have added this line to package.json

It worked for me

```
jest --runInBand --detectOpenHandles --forceExit
```

Comment: More info here: [https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--forceexit](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--forceexit)

Answer (score 22):

For me it was a different issue I was using supertest to test routes itself so I had to close the connection to the server itself.

```
afterAll(done => {
    server.close();
    done();
});
```

You can start server in beforeAll block and close in after all:

```
beforeAll(() => {
   server = app.listen(someRandomNumberHere); // Random number is needed to avoid using same port in different tests if you run in parallel
})

afterAll(() => {
   server.close()
})
```

Additional details in case not clear:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});
module.exports = app;
```

And in index.js or which ever you use to boot up import this something like this:

```js
const app = require('./app'); // assuming app.js is in the same directory
```

If this is not the case for you [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7287) might have something for you

Comment: what is the server variable ?

Comment: Updated the answer @amarnathharish let me know if clear

Answer (score 15):

Adding

```js
jest.useFakeTimers();
```

at the beginning of the test suite fixed it for me.

Might come from timers defined in components part of the render (like throttled buttons, mocks etc..).

Comment: Geez wow. Thanks for this. If jest/enzyme would simply just unmount a functional component correctly I feel this wouldn't even be necessary but thanks for saving me hours regardless. I put in an three dot ellipses, fully tested that the setInterval ran an cleared in the UI. Wrote the tests and still can't get coverage on the return which clears it.

Comment: unbelieveable.  This actually worked.

Answer (score 14):

I was having the same issue but in my package.json file i added `"test": "jest --detectOpenHandles"` and ran `npm test --detectOpenHandles`. I didn't get the error message this time. Maybe you can try doing that.

Comment: I guess `--runInBand`, [which is set with `--detectOpenHandles` implicitly](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#detectopenhandles), fixed the issue in that case.

Comment: This shoud be a suggestion to detect what is causing the issue but not to resolve that.

Comment: This just suppresses the error message because it switches on diagnostics - it does nothing to solve the error, and will not allow the tests to exit successfully.

Answer (score 14):

On my side, I just separate `app.listen()` from my app.
So with express, your app finish with an export.

```
// index.js
module.exports = app;
```

And just create another file to listen the port.

```
// server.js
const app = require('./index')
app.listen(...)
```

And if you import just the index (app `index.js`) in your tests, it should work with no extra config.
Of course your need to adjust the start of your express app. It should use now `server.js`.

Comment: Thank you! do you know why moving app.listen outside on the file works?

Comment: This was the case for me thanks. I'm using the request function from supertest and it doesn't need the server to run so I separated the app.listen from it. Also here's a complete example of such a separation for future readers: https://tutorialedge.net/typescript/creating-rest-api-express-typescript/#our-appts-file

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    afterAll(async(done) => {
  // Closing the DB connection allows Jest to exit successfully.
  try {
    await mongoose.connection.close();
    done()
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    done()
  }
  // done()
})
```

Comment: How exactly did that work? in `afterAll` you can either return a promise or call the `done` callback. you can't do both, it'll throw an error!

Answer (score 3):

For Firebase I had to call cleanup()

```
import {
    assertFails,
    assertSucceeds,
    initializeTestEnvironment,
    RulesTestEnvironment,
} from "@firebase/rules-unit-testing";
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

it('creates a new user document in firebase', async () => {
    const testEnv = await initializeTestEnvironment({
        projectId: "appname-test",
        firestore: {
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 8088
        }
    });

    const alice = testEnv.authenticatedContext("alice");

    await assertSucceeds(setDoc(doc(alice.firestore(), "users", "alice"), {
        fname: "Alice",
        lname: "Wonderland",
        dob: "18/01/1999",
        email: "alice@example.com"
    }));

    return await testEnv.cleanup();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this one

"test": "jest --runInBand --force-exit"

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 2):

## 2023 clean & simple oneliner

Inspiration from Saleh's answer but you don't have to use done.

Put this at the end of the test file:

```
afterAll(() => mongoose.connection.close())
```

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue but, I was using the `pg` module with my NodeJS Express app. I want to post this for those using this stack as well if it helps them.

Essentially, `supertest` creates a server connection, which some people might get the TCPSERVERWRAP error because it doesn't get closed, regardless whether I use async/await or the jest `done` callback. So, this has to be closed after each test. On top of that, the database connection remains open so I mocked it.

Closing the server connection and mocking `pg` together solved the error for me.

`products.tests.ts`

```js
import request from 'supertest'
import { Pool } from 'pg'
import app from '../app'
import type { Server } from 'http'

jest.mock('pg')

const { ROUTE_VERSION = '/v1' } = process.env
const route = (path: string) => [ROUTE_VERSION, path].join('')
const pool = new Pool()
let server: Server

beforeEach(() => {
   server = app.listen(4000)
})

afterEach(() => {
   server.close()
})

describe('GET /products', () => {
   it('returns array of products', async () => {
      await request(server)
         .get(route('/products'))
         .expect(200)
         .expect((res) => {
            expect(pool.query).toBeCalledTimes(1)
            expect(res.body).toBeInstanceOf(Array)
            expect(res.body).not.toHaveLength(0)
         })
   })
})
```

UPDATE: Meant to use `beforeEach` and `afterEach` to close the server after EACH test, otherwise, it still remains open like before.

UPDATE 2: Using async/await otherwise, it will always pass because `request` is asynchronous and doesn't complete unless you wait for it to finish.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem due to not closing the database connection after all the test cases runs. It can be done using jest.config.js and adding a new file to root folder which will globally close the database connection after all the test cases.

In jest.config.js file add the following to the module.exports ,

```
module.exports = {
   setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/runAfterAllTests.ts'],
}
```

Then add runAfterAllTests.ts to src folder.

runAfterAllTests.ts will globally close the db connection. For mongodb it should be something like this.

```
import { client } from './database/connect';

global.afterAll(async () => {
  await client.close();
});
```

This will close the db connection after all the tests and fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually happens when there are some async operations that have not finished by the the time jest is trying to exit.

in app.js export app and server

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();


const server = app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('App is listening on port 3000');
});


module.exports = { app, server };
```

in test.js

```
const request = require('supertest');
const { app, server } = require('../app');

describe('Monitoring Routes', () => {

    afterAll(() => {
        server.close();
    });

    it('should respond with status 200 for /path1/path2', async () => {
        const response = await request(app).get('/path1/path2');
        expect(response.status).toBe(200);
    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

In NestJs apps, where you have something like

```
app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
await app.init();
```

Just add this in your test file

```
afterAll(done => {
    app.close()
    done()
})
```

You can as well use async

```
afterAll(async() => {
    await app.close()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem is that I use Sequilize ORM and I forgot to close it at the end of testing inside the afterAll function callback.

This is my code:

```
afterAll((done) => {
    MatrixTableHeaderCol.destroy({
        where: {},
        force: true
    }).then(() => {
        done();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For those experiencing this when working with Firebase, you likely have to call testEnv.cleanup()

```
let testEnv;

beforeAll(async () => {
  // Silence expected rules rejections from Firestore SDK. Unexpected rejections
  // will still bubble up and will be thrown as an error (failing the tests).
  setLogLevel("error");
  testEnv = await initializeTestEnvironment({
    projectId: projectId,
    firestore: {
      rules: readFileSync("firestore.rules", "utf8"),
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8080,
    },
  });
});


afterAll(async () => {
    await testEnv.cleanup();
})
```